# How do I sign an unsigned IPA?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, ipa, xcodebuild

I have generated an IPA file unsigned with *xcodebuild* utility and now my customer want to sign it. 
It is possible to sign it with an existing provisioning file generated with a developer account?
Another question, it is possible to use a command line related to xcode to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An IPA is simply a .zip archive. Here is a example script to get the idea

```
IPA=$1
PROVISION="/path/to/nameOfProfile.mobileprovision"
CERTIFICATE="iPhone Developer: nameOfCertificate (2472ZKDHVF2A)" # must exist in keychain
# unzip the ipa
unzip -q "$IPA"
# remove the signature
rm -rf Payload/*.app/_CodeSignature Payload/*.app/CodeResources
# replace the provision
cp "$PROVISION" Payload/*.app/embedded.mobileprovision
#copy existing entitlements to use it for resigning
cp Payload/*.app//archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent entitlements.plist
# sign with the new certificate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "$CERTIFICATE" --entitlements "entitlements.plist" Payload/*.app
# zip it 
zip -qr newIpaName.ipa Payload
#clean up
rm -f entitlements.plist
rm -rf Payload
```

To find the name of the Certificate:

- Open "Keychain Access"
- Right+click on the Certificate -> "Get Info"
- Copy and use "Common Name"

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Can you tell me:
CERTIFICATE="iPhone Developer: nameOfCertificate (2472ZKDHVF2A)"
Is the name of the file <NAME_CERTIFICATE>.cer  or another thing?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Sorry.. What is the "entitlements.plist" reference used in your script? Is a particular file or something I've to generate? Thanks in advance..

Comment: It should exist in in your ipa. No need to do anything.

Comment: I get "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent: No such file or directory", what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following app:

https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign